# Window / door install - is it ok to use no Z flashing at the top and bottom if there's trim sealed well all around it with a high quality product?

Tags: doors, windows, waterproofing, sealing, flashing

Would there be any issue to not using metal flashing that protrudes past the siding (such as Z flashing) when installing a vinyl nail-fin window?

The plan would be to put 4-in trim all around it tucked under the small outside lip and seal the edges and behind the trim with OSI Quad Max with a generous amount / multiple beads. The trim is LP SmartSide 440 Trim if that matters and I would plan to seal cut ends by painting with acrylic paint per the instructions.

The same goes with a front door (i.e. no header trim) though still doing a sill pan.

Comment: No amount of caulk, irrespective of the quality, is a substitute for proper water shedding techniques.  Done right, you should need little or no caulk.

Comment: Exposed caulk is a maintenance item and will fail eventually. It will need to be redone every number of years. This is normally done by painters. I would not rely on something that is above a window, hard to see, unless on  ladder to be maintained properly. If that caulk fails the whole window opening will be prone to rot.

Comment: I believe your question could be answered if you ask it this way. How do I install windows with no subsiding over the framing, using LP siding panels and keep the integrity of the waterproofing layer? or something like that.... just a thought. Throwing it out there based on the other question along the same lines.

Answer (score 1):

From personal experience.

My professional installer skipped using the Z flashing.

A Year later there was leaking.

Thanks to the warranty coverage they removed the glass sliding doors and installed with Z flashing.

The problem is with the type of calc used. It will crack over time.

Comment: Good answer. I had a contractor install windows without the proper flashing. Leaked. He kept putting on more caulk which didn't help. I got a roofer to apply proper flashing and got him to pay for it. 20 years later, no leaks.